# Oracle - GROUPING_ID with GROUPING SETS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I would like to verify my understanding based on an example as this will be used for constructing an equivalent query for my project. This is an example quoted from https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets#grouping_sets

```
SELECT fact_1_id,
       fact_2_id,
       fact_3_id,
       SUM(sales_value) AS sales_value,
       GROUPING_ID(fact_1_id, fact_2_id, fact_3_id) AS grouping_id
FROM   dimension_tab
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((fact_1_id, fact_2_id), (fact_1_id, fact_3_id))
ORDER BY fact_1_id, fact_2_id, fact_3_id;
```

Based on the query above,

1. Can I say that there will be two subtototals, with the first being group by `FACT_1_ID, FACT_2_ID` and the other group by `FACT_1_ID, FACT_3_ID`?
2. The `GROUPING_ID` for 1 refers to group by `FACT_1_ID, FACT_2_ID`? Whereas the `GROUPING_ID` for 2 refers to group by `FACT_1_ID, FACT_3_ID`?
3. In continuation from point 2. Since `GROUPING_ID` for 1 refers to group by `FACT_1_ID, FACT_2_ID`, hence the column `FACT_3_ID`  remains `NULL` as it's not being used as the `GROUP BY` clause.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUPING_ID is calculated by this formula. `BIN_TO_NUM(grouping(fact_1_id),GROUPING(fact_2_id),GROUPING(fact_3_id))`

Bin_to_num convert binary value to number. 
You can do reverse calculation. 
if GROUPING_ID=1 => BIN_TO_NUM(0,0,1) = 1 -> fact_3 = null
if GROUPING_ID=2 => BIN_TO_NUM(0,1,0) = 2  ->fact_2 = null
Position of "1" indicate which column has been replaced by null during grouping.
Is it understandable?

Comment: Does that means that '1' means the GROUP BY clause will ignore/leave out that particular column? i.e. Meaning all the '0' will be included in the group by clause to generate a subtotal.

Thanks for the insights into what really happens behind the scene. Helps a lot in understanding!